# Problem with race condition on custom command

Tags: javascript, redux, cypress

My app makes an XHR request on load and saves the response in my redux store. I have added a middleware so that Cypress can listen to the redux update.

In my Cypress tests, I want a generic command where I can attach a listener and do some logic based on the redux action.
This is what I have so far:

`commands.js`

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('onReduxAction', actionType => 
  new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
    cy.on('emit:reduxAction', ({action} => {
      if (action.type === actionType) {
        resolve(action.type);
      }
    });
  });
);
```

`spec.js`

```js
before(() => {
  cy.visit();
  cy.onReduxAction('MY_ACTION').then(data => {
    // some logic
  });
});
```

This seems to be prone to the race condition where `MY_ACTION` can be triggered (as a result of `cy.visit();`) before the listener is attached. I tried the following too, but it doesn't work since the unresolved promise prevents the visit from running:

```js
cy.onReduxAction('MY_ACTION').then(data => {
  // some logic
});
cy.visit();
```

---

Is there a way to have custom commands return a promise without having to be resolved before resuming execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, use a plain function to set up an on-going event listener.

If you are using a custom command to give you something globally available, the advice from Cypress is to just import helper functions as needed. Or you can add them to the `Cypress` global (as long as the name does not conflict).

**cypress/support/helpers.js**

```js
export const onReduxAction = (actionType) => {
  return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
    cy.on('emit:reduxAction', ({action}) => {
      if (action.type === actionType) {
        resolve(action.type);
      }
    })
  })
}
```

**Test**

```js
import { onReduxAction } from '../support/helpers.js';

before(() => {
  onReduxAction('MY_ACTION').then(data => {
    // some logic
  });
  cy.visit();
})
```

From [docs - Promise](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/promise.html#Examples)

> Cypress is promise aware so if you return a promise from inside of commands like `.then()`, Cypress **will not continue until those promises resolve**.

It's the same with a custom command which is returning a Chainable that expects a concrete (resolved) subject to pass on to the next command.

---

I'd be interested to see how you dispatch the event that `cy.on('emit:reduxAction', ...)` is picking up, was under the impression that we were restricted to the events listed here [Catalog of Events](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#Event-Types).

---

You might also get it working by coordinating the visit and the listener with a `onBeforeLoad` event

```js
cy.visit('http://example.com', {                // start the page load
  onBeforeLoad: () => {                         // set up listener ahead of loading
    cy.on('emit:reduxAction', ({action}) => {
      if (action.type === actionType) {
        // some logic
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Regarding your question about the event, I have added a middleware to redux that looks like this: `const cypressMiddleware = s => n => a => { if (window.hasOwnProperty('Cypress')) { window.Cypress.emit('emit:reduxAction', {store: s, action: a}); } return n(a); };`. This lets me do logic on the action type, the action value and the current store state.

Comment: Cheers - I found [todomvc-redux-kuker](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/03/20/using-events-emitted-from-your-application-during-end-to-end-tests/) but your way looks much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Steve's answer (use a JS function) is the better one, but just to illustrate how to fool Cypress:

If you wrap the promise in an object Cypress will not recognize it as a Promise, and therefore not wait for it to resolve.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('onReduxAction', actionType => {
  const promise = new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
    cy.on('emit:reduxAction', ({action}) => {
      if (action.type === actionType) {
        resolve(action.type);
      }
    });
  });
  return { promise }
});

cy.onReduxAction('MY_ACTION').then(promiseWrapper => {  // Cypress then method
  promiseWrapper.promise.then(data => {                 // Promise then method
    // some logic
  })
});

cy.visit('');
```